# java: Is there any way to avoid writing named class? (variable has not been initialized)

Tags: java

In one place (and only one) i need a wrapper around the interface passed to the method. If possible I would like to avoid complicating the code by writing separate class for that purpose, so I wanted to take a closure approach, but then I run into "variable may not have been initialized" error.

I've found similar problem ( [Final Local Variable may not have been initialized in anonymous inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239046/final-local-variable-may-not-have-been-initialized-in-anonymous-inner-class) ), but If possible I would like to find a way to go around the problem without writing separate class for the wrapper.

the code:

```
    protected void startListening(LocationRequest request,@Nullable final LocationListener listener) {
    ...
    final LocationListener l = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if(listener != null) {
                listener.onLocationChanged(location);
            }
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, l);
        }
    };
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, request, l);
}
```

Additional details:

- listener passed as a parameter may not have access to the google api client (I use few different ways to provide 'desired location', and just re-use the LocationListener interface in other implementations), so I cannot remove it from location updates from it's onLocationChanged method
- there may possibly be more than one listener, so I cannot keep it in a class-level variable (I would have to use some collection, and logic to inform which one requested what and when)
- the usual use-case for location requests in this code is to get a single location update upon user's action (e.g. opening the map, or clicking "refresh" button) - that's why i want to remove listener right away.

Comment: Have you tried passing `LocationListener.this` instead of `l` in the call to `removeLocationUpdates()`?

Comment: I get "com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener is not an enclosing class" - didn't know I can use 'this' in inner classes, which class it would refer to?
if 'this' would refer to the inner class, then i can just use 'this' in place of 'l'.

Comment: Yes, of course you can. And indeed `LocationListener.this` is the wrong syntax.

Comment: thanks, that solved my problem, and simplified the code (no need for local variable 'l')

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot the syntax with the class name in front of `this`, such as `Something.this`, is used for *named* inner classes, not anonymous inner classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual in Java, when you have an initializer (or any assignment statement), first the expression to assign is calculated, and only then it is assigned to the variable.

This is also true for your local variable `l` - at the time you create the anonymous class, `l` does not yet have a value - it will only have one after the instance of the anonymous class has been constructed and assigned to it.

So of course, you can't refer to an uninitialized variable from a closure, and that's the reason for the issue you had.

The solution is to use `this` to refer to that instance from inside it, rather than using `l`. You can use `this` in anonymous classes, as opposed to lambda expressions, in which `this` refers to the enclosing class.

Comment: (Converted into an answer from the comments in the OP)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to pass the local variable `l` to `removeLocationUpdates()`, which is what triggers the error, just pass `this` as the argument. That works because in the context of that anonymous class, `this` refers to the anonymous class instance(`LocationListener`)

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
```